# Как плавно переместить часть блока за границы родительского контейнера?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как плавно переместить блок влево за границу родительского контейнера и при этом скрыть перемещенную часть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код, который у вас есть. Также уточните, используете ли вы какие-то готовые фреймворки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для родителя используйте `overflow: hidden`, для "ребенка" есть несколько вариантов `position: absolute`, `position: relative`, `margin-left`.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 180px 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
}
.block + .block {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.block1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: -50%;
  border-color: green;
}

.block2 {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  border-color: blue;
}
.block3 {
  margin-left: -50%;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block1"></div>
  <div class="block block2"></div>
  <div class="block block3"></div>
  <div class="block block4"></div>
</div>
```